# Indonesia Banyak diving

Tags: indonesia, diving, sumatra-indonesia

I'll be travelling to Sumatra end of April and would like to go diving near the Banyak Islands. It seems that there once was an agency providing dive tours (Nirvana diving) but it's unclear to me whether this is still the case.

Anyone with recent experiences regarding diving near the Banyak Islands ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not operating any more
I had confirmation from Rius ([Nina's Bungalow](http://banyak-island-bungalow.com))

Comment: I now got confirmation from the owner as well. They are still operating the bungalows but the diving centre has been moved to Pulau Weh.

Comment: @stedes The bungalow in Tailana has never really been related. If you want to snorkel, this (or Nina's) is a great place